# ng-class mix string with angular annotation

Tags: angularjs

If I use this code

```
<td ng-class="'log-level-' + {{log.level | uppercase}}">
```

This is the rendered result:

```
<td ng-class="'log-level-' + WARN" class="log-level-">
```

If I remove the double brackets

```
<td ng-class="'log-level-' + log.level">
```

The rendered result is

```
<td ng-class="'log-level-' + log.level" class="log-level-Warn">
```

Is it not possible to uppercase the second `log.level` property in HTML and mix it with a string?

//EDIT//

NEVER MIND. Typing out the question made me realize I could use wrap the angularjs expression in a string.

```
<td ng-class="'log-level-' + '{{log.level | uppercase}}'">
```

I thought this would just render the `{{log.level | uppercase}}` value as a string but it still processes the expression first.

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-). Since this is not recommended usage, we do not test for this, and changes to AngularJS core may break your code.

Answer (score 0):

Typing out the question made me realize I could use wrap the angularjs expression in a string.

```
 <td ng-class="'log-level-' + '{{log.level | uppercase}}'">
```

I thought this would just render the `{{log.level | uppercase}}` value as a string but it still processes the expression first.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="static-class {{log.level}}">
    Test
</td>
```

I added sample app also check [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/RajamohanShilpa/19pe0qLc/16/)

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
  {{test}}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="static-class">
        Test
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="static-class {{runtimeClass}}">
        Test
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" ng-click="addRuntimeClass()">
    click
  </button>
</div>

var app = angular.module('testApp',[])
app.controller('testCtrl',['$scope', 
function($scope){
    $scope.test='Sample test app';
  $scope.addRuntimeClass = function(){
    $scope.runtimeClass = 'runtime-class'
  }
}])

.static-class{
  display:block;
  color:black;
}

.runtime-class{
  display:block;
  color:red;
}
```